# Updating rows based on another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I created a table called `SALE_REP` with 4 columns, `employee_id`, `name`, `salary` and `commission_pct`.

I populated the `SALE_REP` table from an existing `EMPLOYEES` table. Now I want to update the salaries of some of the employees in the `SALE_REP` table using a subquery based on the values from another table;

```
update sale_rep
set salary = (select salary from employees
  where job_id = 'ad_vp')
where employee_id = (select employee_id from employees 
  where commission_pct = 0.35);
```

But this gets;

```
SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I perform the update successfully?

Comment: Where is `ad_vp` coming from? Are you expecting only one person to have each `job_id`, or the salary to be the same for all employees with that? Maybe you can add some sample data and expected final result.

Comment: i'm trying to upgrade the salaries of employees with 35% commission to that of an employee in the position of ad_vp

Comment: @ Alex- I agree with you, I now understand . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two subqueries, and if you data is based on the standard HR schema's employee table then both will return multiple rows.

The second is straightforward; the `=` needs to be `in`:

```
where employee_id in (select employee_id from employees 
  where commission_pct = 0.35)
```

... which matches three rows in the `employee` table in my schema. (Although as you said your `sale_rep` table is populated from `employees` and has the `commission_pct` column you don't really need to use a subquery here - the filter value exists on the table you're updating, so you could potentially just do `where commission_pct = 0.35`).

The first is more difficult and you'll need to define what you want to actually happen. You could, for example, pick the highest salary from those matching the specified `job_id`:

```
set salary = (select max(salary) from employees
  where job_id = 'SA_REP')
```

I've picked `'SA_REP'` as that looks like it might be a sales rep, and that has 30 matching rows with 20 different values in my schema. Based on your edit, there are two rows in my schema for `AD_VP`, but both have the same salary; in which case using `max()` might be OK, or you could use `distinct`:

```
set salary = (select distinct salary from employees
  where job_id = 'AD_VP')
```

But that is very specific to the data you have at this point in time, so it isn't going to be a good general pattern.

Putting those together you could do:

```
select employee_id, salary from sale_rep where commission_pct = 0.35;

EMPLOYEE_ID     SALARY
----------- ----------
        156      10000
        157       9500
        158       9000

update sale_rep
set salary = (select max(salary) from employees
  where job_id = 'AD_VP')
where employee_id in (select employee_id from employees 
  where commission_pct = 0.35);  

3 rows updated.

select employee_id, salary from sale_rep where commission_pct = 0.35;

EMPLOYEE_ID     SALARY
----------- ----------
        156      17000
        157      17000
        158      17000
```

More generally there probably needs to be some connection between the row you're updating and the value you're choosing though, other than the filter on commission percentage, which doesn't look related to the job. That does seem to be what you want in this case though.

Comment: Thanks I've  taken note of your suggestions what I actually intend to acheive is to update multiple rows using subqueries. However ,    'AD_VP'    in my schema just has 2 rows and both have the same value which I think shouldnt be a problems they are not of different values.

Comment: @ayoola - it's still two rows - you need to use distinct, or an aggregate (like max), so the subquery only returns a single row. That's what I showed in the answer. Oracle won't guess that it should only return one row just because it could with that specific data, you have to tell it to, and how to do that.